# Magento SQL Error, Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: php, sql, database, magento

Hi members of stackoverflow, recently i was working on my magento website and i had to make my SQl database size smaller so i went into phpmyadmin on siteground and truncated "log_visitor"  and then went back to my website and everything worked fine, about five hours later i went back to my website

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '426' for key 'PRIMARY'" error

and i have no idea how to fix this, would i just go delete entry 426 ? So could i please get some help ? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figured out how to fix this problem, i went into the database where the error was occuring using phpMyAdmin and selected the "log_visitor_inf" table and truncated it, this clears all keys and in turn stops the duplicate key error.